# Vista Mini setup Drivers

Tags: windows-vista, unattended

I have created an answer file however whenever I run sysprep the video adapter driver keeps being removed and a basic one put on.  The sysprep all works and the mini setup is automated to the point where I need to login and reinstall the video driver.  There are so many options I am assuming that there is a way to add a little ol video driver considering the options in WSIM.  Has anybody come across a similar  issue that knows where to find the options for the drivers in the minisetup (answer file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked online. This is not my answer but it worked for me.
The fix is to add Microsoft Windows Pnpsysprep_6.0 to pass 3 and under the setting PersistAllDeviceInstalls set this to True. 
I tested this after I made this setting to the answerfile and it worked a treat.

Farseeker, thanks for you respnse.

Comment: The source of this answer was from this location
http://h30434.www3.hp.com/psg/board/message?board.id=Display&message.id=1187

Answer (score 0):

You can add drivers to a WAIK installation image (WIM). I've only ever done it this way before I'm afraid, not with sysprepping, but if you get a WIM image at the end of it you might still be able to do it?